# Exponent questions algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I solve the following two exponent questions?

(1) The first question is

$$\left(\frac{x^{-2}+y^{-1}}{xy^2}\right)^{-1}$$

I got $\quad \displaystyle \frac{-xy^{-2}}{x^2+y},\;\;$but this does not seem to be correct.

(2) My second question is

$$\left(\frac{3}{A^{-3}B^{-2}}\right)^{-2}$$

I got $\quad\displaystyle \frac{A^6B^4}{1/9},\quad$ but my book's answer is $\quad\displaystyle \frac{1}{9A^6B^4}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We are not solving, we are *simplifying*: For the first, note that

> $$\left(\frac{x^{-2}+y^{-1}}{xy^2}\right)^{-1}\;=\; \frac{xy^2}{x^{-2} + y^{-1}}\;=\;\frac{xy^2}{\large\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{y}}$$

Try now to multiply numerator and denominator by $x^2y$:

$$\frac{xy^2}{\left(\large\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{y}\right)}\cdot \frac{(x^2y)}{(x^2y)} \quad = \quad\frac {x\cdot x^2 \cdot y^2 \cdot y}{\left(\large\frac{x^2y}{x^2} + \frac{x^2y}{y}\right)}\quad =\quad \frac{x^3y^3}{y + x^2} $$

---

For the second, again, we are simplifying:

$$\left(\frac{3}{A^{-3}B^{-2}}\right)^{-2} \quad = \quad \frac{3^{-2}}{A^{(-3)(-2)}B^{(-2)(-2)}}\quad = \quad \frac{1/9}{A^6B^4}\quad =\quad \frac{1}{9A^6B^4}$$

---

(as per my now deleted comment below) 
Alternatively, for the second problem, we proceed as follows:

$$\left(\frac{3}{A^{-3}B^{-2}}\right)^{-2}\quad = \quad\left(\frac{A^{-3}B^{-2}}{3}\right)^2 \quad=\quad \frac{A^{-6}B^{-4}}{9} \quad = \quad \frac{1}{9A^6B^4}$$

Comment: One quick question I have on the second problem is dont you flip the fraction when you have a negative exponent.

Comment: I strongly encourage the OP to check the reason for each step in this answer. If you are unsure of what rule is applied to each step, do some research and/or ask here.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez There are often more than one way to simplify these kinds of expressions.

Comment: Then is the way I did it initially correct or incorrect?

Comment: Fernando: you can flip, but you can also multiply through by the negative exponent (since the terms in the numerator and denominator are all multiplied), so each term's exponent can be multiplied by -2, which simplifies the denominator right away. In the first problem, note that at the start, the numerator had a sum, so we can't just multiply through by the exponent.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez You made a mistake somewhere along the way, but it is impossible for us to say where since you have not shown your work. See [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279637/exponent-questions-algebra/279665#279665) for the correct way to "flip" the fraction as the first step.

Comment: Oh I think I see the error of my way now you can flip first then do the exponent I think.

Comment: Is it clear, now, Fernando?

Comment: yes I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

You got

> $$\frac{-xy^{-2}}{x^2+y}$$

Here's what I got:
$$\left(\frac{x^{-2}+y^{-1}}{xy^2}\right)^{-1}=\left(\frac{xy^2}{x^{-2}+y^{-1}}\right)=\left(\frac{xy^2}{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y}} \right)=\left(\frac{xy^2}{\frac{y+x^2}{yx^2}} \right)=xy^2\cdot\left(\frac{yx^2}{y+x^2} \right)=\frac{x^3y^3}{y+x^2}$$

Comment: Same thing I got, so I think this is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

To Solve Problem 1.

We are going to begin by seperating the fraction into two parts (both still underneath one big -1st power)

This leads us to x^-3/y^2 + y^-3/x. After moving the powers to their correct locations we get:

1/(y^2*x^3) + 1(x*y^3).

Now factoring out 1/(x*y^2) from both sides we get.

1/(x*y^2)*[1/(x^2) + 1/(y)]

finding an LCD (least common denominator) for both fractions we can rewrite it as.

(1/x*y^2)*[(y + x^2)/(x^2*y)]

Placing back the factored fraction we end up with:

(y + x^2)/(x^3 * y^3)

and now applying the negative first power (REMEMBER FROM THE START!)

(x^3*y^3)/(y + x^2)

Is the correct answer.

To Solve Number 2.

We begin with the expression (3/(A^(-3) * B^(-2)))^(-2).

First we bring up the A and B (since we can w/ negative exponents!)

so we get (3*A^3 * B^2)^(-2). Now we can evaluate that -2nd power in two steps. First we evaluate it as a 2nd power and then a -1, both we know how to do.

So after evaluating the 2 we end up with:

(9*A^6*B^4)^(-1)

After the -1 we end up with:

1/(9*A^6*B^4)

Which is what you should get! Good Luck :)

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/464/264) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/161783). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to simplify the second expression from your question:

$$\left(\frac{3}{A^{-3}B^{-2}}\right)^{-2} = \left(\frac{A^{-3}B^{-2}}{3}\right)^{2} = \left(\frac{A^{-6}B^{-4}}{9}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{9A^{6}B^{4}}\right).$$